# How to implement multi relationship in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I’m trying to design a database to use with ASP.net MVC application.  Here is the scenario: There are three entities and users can post their comments for each of these different entities. I just wonder how just put one table for Comments and link all other entities to it. Obviously, Comments table needs 3 references (foreign key) to those tables but as you know these foreign keys can’t be null and just one of them can be filled for each row. Is there any better way than implementing three different tables for each entity’s comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either: One comment table per Entity type

Or: one master Entity tables with child Comments and EntityType specific tables.

- EntityMaster: EntityID, foo, bar
- Comments: EntityID, CommentID, UserID, ... PK is (EntityID, CommentID etc)

For the 3 Entity tables, PK is EntityID

- EntityOne: EntityID, EntityTypeID (check constraint = 1), ...
- EntityTwo: EntityID, EntityTypeID (check constraint = 2), ...
- EntityThree: EntityID, EntityTypeID (check constraint = 3), ...

There is no shortcut or elegance in having one comment table for 3 parents: it's wrong in database design terms.

Personally, I'd probably go for option 1...

Edit, on reflection:

Sometimes you have to look at the usage of the data.

If the 3 entities are used separately, on separate screens, don't link to each other then it'd be option 1.

If the 3 entities are used and displayed together, then option 2 makes more sense because you can pull data together more easily.

Comment: +1 For pointing out how "distributed" keys can be simulated with check constraints. However, I'd argue there are times (not here) when the latter approach is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If you connect all three entity tables to the same comment table, you will not be able to have referential integrity through foreign keys. In that scenario, you would have one "key" column and one "entity-type" column in your comment table. To get the comments for a cerain entity, you would need to filter by entity-type.

Personaly I would prefer three comment tables with the same structure, which can be joined by union to get all comments for all entities.

Comment: I agree with the multiple comment tables with same structure suggestion. - as long as the columns are consistent it should be easy to consolidate the comments into a view as well.

Answer (score 1):

You db structure like at image bellow. You need to create CommentHistory when you create Entity1 or Entity2.

[image]

So if you need get all comments for Entity1 you just need:

```
Select * from Comment where CommentHistoryId = 5 -- '5' it CommentHistoryId from Entity1
```